# How to configure `apollo` CLI properly for a project that doesn't use Apollo Engine?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to use [apollo-tooling](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output) to generate TypeScript types using my graphQL server introspection result (`schema.json`).  I do not use Apollo Engine and want to know if there is a config setting to instruct `apollo` cli to stop trying to find my remote schema.

command used:

```
apollo client:codegen \
    --includes=./src/queries/** \
    --localSchemaFile=./schema.json \
    --target=typescript \
    --tagName=gql \
    --outputFlat \
    src/schema_types.ts
```

Current error:

```
Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "xxxxxx-7926": Error: Error in "Loading schema for xxxxxx-7926": Error: Unable to get schema from Apollo Engine for service xxxxxx-7926
```

Comment: Do you have any configuration in your apollo.config.js or package.json?

Comment: Nope, I tried using an apollo config but that didn’t help. Honestly, I had so much trouble with this new apollo project that I reverted to using the older, ‘apollo-codegen’ package that I have used previously and experienced no problems generating types that way.